# Advice before moving dual boot to larger laptop drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, transfer

I'm fairly new to Linux (and fairly old too so learning isn't coming quickly).

I'm running a laptop with dual boot Win10 and Kubuntu, but for various reasons, partly down to ignorance, and partly down to switching from Mint KDE (as they withdraw long term support) to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I've got a messy partition structure:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type  

/dev/sda1             2048   24578047   24576000  11.7G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda2  *      24578048  420874239  396296192   189G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda3        420874240  421980159    1105920   540M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda4        421980160 1953523711 1531543552 730.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)  
/dev/sda5        421984256 1211076607  789092352 376.3G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda6       1211078656 1953523711  742445056   354G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The important partitions are `/sda2` (Windows), and the extended partitions `/sda5` (Ubuntu) and `/sda6` (shared partition for data for both OS).

I don't know if it is wise to have Ubuntu on an extended partition, but that arose out of me running out of partitions whilst trying to keep the old Mint just in case.

What is important is that:

1. I keep both OSs on the same drive as I cannot yet dispense with Windows and being a laptop only one drive is practical
2. I have a shared partition for data for both systems
3. I am able to add a new partition at some future stage should I need
   to
4. I have room on a Linux partition (or extended) for a planned
   attempt at virtual Windows via VMWare

Therefore advice on a structure and then mode of transferring the existing system from the 1Tb drive to a new 2TB drive.  I'm reasonably ok with Clonezilla and Gparted and have Win10 and Kubuntu installation media.

Additionally, I've just spent two days recovering from Windows 1903 update rudely borking my GRUB2.  Will I have to repeat those steps?  I'm set to MBR.

Comment: Some things easy, some things not so easy. Is your computer an old BIOS machine, or is it new enough to be a UEFI machine? With the new 2TB drive, you'll want to use GPT partition tables, unlike the MBR partition tables you have now. The spare NTFS partition is the correct way to share files between the OSs. Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema HP Elitebook 8440 64bit UEFI supported.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema  Was looking for you to come back to me.  Apparently UEFI on this model is experimental, unsupported and I couldn't get it to work so stuck with MBR.  Tried backing up Windows (Macrium), installing new instance of Win10, redoing all my partitions and putting the Linux partitions back, but Windows wouldn't run or repair even when restored.  Ended up doing a disk to disk with Clonezilla and will sort out all the partitions with Gparted in my own time.  Off topic but I can't get to grips with this Markdown syntax or the instructions.  Is there a sandbox?

Comment: I don't know how to respond to your comment. Does Windows work now? What happened when you tried UEFI? I don't know what sandbox you're referring to.

Comment: I have done a drive to drive copy using Clonezilla and then extended the existing Linux partitions with Gparted.  That is mostly working, smbtree shows nothing but that may not be anything to do with this exercise.  When I tried UEFI and did a fresh Windows install on a clean disk it still reported MBR.  However I was using a USB stick and I don't know if the installed followed the MBR/UEFI state used at creation time.  By sandbox I meant somewhere to try to learn and test Markdown so as to avoid the formatting mess in my OP.

Comment: I really think that you should just start over. Set your computer to UEFI mode. Manually lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive). Install Windows fresh. Install Ubuntu fresh. Manually copy over data from the 1TB to the 2TB. I think the long term results will be better. For some markdown help, please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt and only in BIOS mode from MBR. So if you have newer UEFI system better to do total reinstall. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs. You can restore data, but not images of partitions as MBR is different than gpt.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  This is my main machine and now it is operational I'm not now inclined to spend further time for the moment.  I'm somewhat deterred by the msg on the BIOS screen that UEFI on this model is experimental and unsupported.  Now I understand UEFI/GPT better I have made a note of this page in my installation notes and will revisit at a future stage.  I was unaware of the need to create the USB in the appropriate mode and understand it probably would have worked at I used a DVD.

Comment: @heynnema  This is the sort of thing that is helpful for those unfamiliar with the syntax of the markup https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus

Comment: @AnthonyL Didn't my prior link of https://askubuntu.com/editing-help provide you with the markdown syntax that you might need? Also, if my answer, shown below, is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I had already looked at that to avoid making the mess I ended up making of the **fdisk-l** results.  Even now it is not clear whether "pre and code" or just "pre" are needed.  Bear in mind my focus is on my problem not on learning a strange editor, I don't think I've ever used a back-tick in my life.  I wonder how many other newbies need their first posts edited?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you can backup partitions` content with fsarchiver and after partitioning your new drive as you like, restore them. Then There is two steps needed:

1. Installing GRUB on new Drive.
2. Change your fstab file to point to the right(new) partition UUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with a drive-to-drive copy using Clonezilla and then extended the existing Linux partitions with Gparted.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x41205603

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048   24578047   24576000  11.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *      24578048  420874239  396296192   189G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        420874240  421980159    1105920   540M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        421980160 3907028991 3485048832   1.6T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        421982208 1852712959 1430730752 682.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1852715008 3907028991 2054313984 979.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The more optimal suggestions of UEFI/GPT will be left until I upgrade to a more modern laptop with certified, not experimental, UEFI support.